# Storing collections of items that an algorithm might need

Tags: c++

I have a class MyClass that stores a collection of PixelDescriptor* objects. MyClass uses a function specified by a Strategy pattern style object (call it DescriptorFunction) to do something for each descriptor:

```
void MyFunction()
{
 descriptorA = DescriptorCollection[0];
 for_each descriptor in DescriptorCollection
  {
  DescriptorFunction->DoSomething(descriptor)
  }
}
```

However, this only makes sense if the descriptors are of a type that the DescriptorFunction knows how to handle. That is, not all DescriptorFunction's know how to handle all descriptor types, but as long as the descriptors that are stored are of the type that the visitor that is specified knows about, all is well.

How would you ensure the right type of descriptors are computed? Even worse, what if the strategy object needs more than one type of descriptor?

I was thinking about making a composite descriptor type, something like:

```
class CompositeDescriptor
{
 std::vector<PixelDescriptor*> Descriptors;
}
```

Then a CompositeDescriptor could be passed to the DescriptorFunction. But again, how would I ensure that the correct descriptors are present in the CompositeDescriptor?

As a more concrete example, say one descriptor is Color and another is Intensity. One Strategy may be to average Colors. Another strategy may be to average Intensities. A third strategy may be to pick the larger of the average color or the average intensity.

I've thought about having another Strategy style class called DescriptorCreator that the client would be responsible for setting up. If a ColorDescriptorCreator was provided, then the ColorDescriptorFunction would have everything it needs. But making the client responsible for getting this pairing correct seems like a bad idea.

Any thoughts/suggestions?

EDIT: In response to Tom's comments, a bit more information:

Essentially DescriptorFunction is comparing two pixels in an image. These comparisons can be done in many ways (besides just finding the absolute difference between the pixels themseles). For example 1) Compute the average of corresponding pixels in regions around the pixels (centered at the pixels). 2) Compute a fancier "descriptor" which typically produces a vector at each pixel and average the difference of the two vectors element-wise. 3) compare 3D points corresponding to the pixel locations in external data, etc etc.

I've run into two problems.

1) I don't want to compute everything inside the strategy (if the strategy just took the 2 pixels to compare as arguments) because then the strategy has to store lots of other data (the image, there is a mask involved describing some invalid regions, etc etc) and I don't think it should be responsible for that.

2) Some of these things are expensive to compute. I have to do this millions of times (the pixels being compared are always difference, but the features at each pixel do not change), so I don't want to compute any feature more than once. For example, consider the strategy function compares the fancy descriptors. In each iteration, one pixels is compared to all other pixels. This means in the second iteration, all of the features would have to be computed again, which is extremely redundant. This data needs to be stored somewhere that all of the strategies can access it - this is why I was trying to keep a vector in the main client.

Does this clarify the problem? Thanks for the help so far!

Answer (score 0):

The first part sounds like a [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) could be appropriate.  A visitor can ignore any types it doesn't want to handle.

If they require more than one descriptor type, then it is a different abstraction entirely.  Your description is somewhat vague, so it's hard to say exactly what to do.  I suspect that you are over thinking it.  I say that because generally choosing arguments for an algorithm is a high level concern.

I think the best advice is to try it out.

I would write each algorithm with the concrete arguments (or stubs if its well understood).  Write code to translate the collection into the concrete arguments.  If there is an abstraction to be made, it should be apparent while writing your translations.  Writing a few choice helper functions for these translations is usually the bulk of the work.

Giving a concrete example of the descriptors and a few example declarations might give enough information to offer more guidance.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'll get back to you soon :)

Comment: I added a few paragraphs to the bottom of the original question.